# How can I sync my World of Goo progress on the iPhone and Mac?

Tags: world-of-goo

I'm playing World of Goo on the iPhone and on stationery Mac sometimes.

How can I sync my World of Goo progress on the iPhone and Mac both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a similar thread on 2dboy forum:

http://goofans.com/forum/world-of-goo/support/2460

> Well, currently it is not possible to
>   transfer save files but when GooTool
>   1.1 come you will be able to transfer files. hope I helped